# How to get the next value in a separate partition in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-partitioning

I have a single database table `affiliations` in the following format:

| author_id | article_id | institution | publication_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | institution_1 | 2010-01-01 |
| 1 | 1 | institution_2 | 2010-01-01 |
| 1 | 2 | institution_2 | 2012-01-01 |
| 1 | 3 | institution_2 | 2014-01-01 |
| 2 | 2 | institution_3 | 2012-01-01 |
| 2 | 4 | institution_3 | 2013-01-01 |

My goal is to infer periods of affiliations between a given author and their institutions, by combining publication dates across the author's consecutive articles where the same institution is on those articles and "consecutive" means published consecutively date-wise. For the most recent article of a given author, it is assumed that the author is still affiliated with the institution/s from that article. So for the data above, for example, I'm looking to return something like the following:

| author_id | institution | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | institution_1 | 2010-01-01 | 2012-01-01 |
| 1 | institution_2 | 2010-01-01 | <current_date> |
| 2 | institution_3 | 2012-01-01 | <current_date> |

Importantly, an author can be affiliated with more than one institution at the same time, i.e. affiliations can overlap for the same author.

I have tried various combinations of leads and partitions in SQL, but one of the issues I'm having is I'm not able to select the next value that is in a different partition (which I think I'll need to do to get the next publication date for a given author on a different article, for example).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might achieve the above in a fairly efficient manner (bearing in mind this will be part of a CTE in a larger query that involves millions of rows)?

Comment: I think you need to clarify the logic that you wish to use for the start and end dates.  For example, it looks like the end date for your first output record is based on the start date of that authors next institution, but the end date for the last record in the output is based on the last publication for that institution.  So, can you clarify the logic?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity! The end date for the last record shouldn't be based on the last publication for that institution, it should be effectively today's date, since if there are no later publications then that author is assumed to still be affiliated with that last institution. I'll update the question now

Answer (score 1):

Try the following left join query:

```
SELECT D.author_id, D.institution, D.start_date, 
       COALESCE(MIN(T.publication_date), CURRENT_DATE) AS end_date
FROM
  (
    SELECT author_id, institution, MIN(publication_date) AS start_date
    FROM affiliations
    GROUP BY author_id, institution
  ) D
LEFT JOIN affiliations T
ON D.author_id = T.author_id AND D.institution <> T.institution
   AND D.start_date < T.publication_date
GROUP BY D.author_id, D.institution, D.start_date
ORDER BY D.author_id, D.institution
```

The output according to your input:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve it is by adding additional subgroup when institution changes:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *,
    CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(institution) OVER(PARTITION BY author_id 
                                               ORDER BY publication_date) AS subgrp
   FROM tab
)
SELECT author_id, institution,
    MIN(publication_date) AS start_date,
    MAX(publication_date) AS end_date
FROM cte
GROUP BY author_id, institution,subgrp
ORDER BY author_id,start_date;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not quite what I'm looking for, because that first row in the output should have an end date of 2012-01-01, corresponding to the date of the author's next article where they were no longer affiliated with that institution.